# Web Api Post Method in Body

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I have simple post method in web api.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test(TestClass model)
{
    return Ok(model);
}
```

The class :

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

When I send a request in body using Postman,
The Content - Type is application/json

```
{ "Code" : "test" }
```

Everything work properly.

When I send a request changing content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I write to

Key:Code Value:Test

in x-www-form-urlencoded

The requests still works .

I would like to ask that are they the same way to send request ?

Is it possible to prevent sending request other content-type except  application/json ?

Thank you for your kind interest.

Comment: I believe this is what you want. Check out this article. http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/

Comment: Thank you! That's right. It helps me